# Is this a SonarQube bug? Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to 'false'; some subsequent code is never executed

Tags: c#, .net, sonarqube

SonarQube detects an issue "Change this condition so that it does not always evaluate to 'false'; some subsequent code is never executed" in the following code.

```
public void SonarPleaseWhy(IList<string> texts)
{
    var chain = new List<string>();

    bool firstItemAdded = false;
    bool otherItemAdded = false;

    foreach (var text in texts)
    {
        if (!firstItemAdded && text.Length == 1)
        {
            chain.Add(text);
            firstItemAdded = true;
        }
        else if (firstItemAdded && text.Length == 2)
        {
            chain.Add(text);
            otherItemAdded = true;
        }
        else if (otherItemAdded && text.Length == 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(',', chain));
            chain.Clear();
            firstItemAdded = false;
            otherItemAdded = false;
        }
        else
        {
            chain.Clear();
            firstItemAdded = false;
            otherItemAdded = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a bug in SonarQube, or some real issue in my code? If the latter, please help me, I don't understand.

SonarQube highlights the part `text.Length == 3` in red and the body of the subsequent elseif block. For some reason, it does not have any problem with the first elseif block.

I've tried to simplify my code, that's how I reached this (almost) minimal reproducible example but still cannot see the reason.

Comment: The conditions are placed in a `foreach` block. `otherItemAdded` could been set to `true` in the previous iteration.

Comment: Can you add a sample `texts` that, when having `SonarPleaseWhy(texts)` called on them, would enter the `otherItemAdded && text.Length == 3` branch and prove SonarQube wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code demonstrates that the body of the `else if (otherItemAdded && text.Length == 3)` can be entered, and also that the `&& text.Length == 3` condition is evaluated and necessary:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Console1;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] test = { "1", "22", "333", "1", "22", "4444" };

        SonarPleaseWhy(test);
    }

    public static void SonarPleaseWhy(IList<string> texts)
    {
        bool firstItemAdded = false;
        bool otherItemAdded = false;

        foreach (var text in texts)
        {
            if (!firstItemAdded && text.Length == 1)
            {
                firstItemAdded = true;
            }
            else if (firstItemAdded && text.Length == 2)
            {
                otherItemAdded = true;
            }
            else if (otherItemAdded && text.Length == 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"It entered the 'if' with text {text}");
                firstItemAdded = false;
                otherItemAdded = false;
            }
            else
            {
                firstItemAdded = false;
                otherItemAdded = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Note that I have elided the code manipulating `chain` from your original code because that plays no part in the logic in question.)

If you run this, you will see the output:

```
It entered the 'if' with text 333
```

Now comment-out the `&& text.Length == 3` part of the condition and run it again. This time the output is:

```
It entered the 'if' with text 333
It entered the 'if' with text 4444
```

This clearly demonstrates both of the points that I asserted above.

Therefore if SonarQube really is warning you about either of those things, it's a false positive (at least, based only on the code you've shown us).

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I've sent a bug report to SonarQube.